# Unicode character equivalent to the underscore on top

Tags: unicode

Is there a character equivalent to the underscore " _ " which occupies the upper position? Dash " - " will not do. If it were me, I would call it upper-score. But I do not see this anywhere.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you seek is generally known as a "macron", "overline", "overscore", or "overbar". It exists at several Unicode code points; which one you want depends on whether you want a macron or an overline (the former being shorter), and whether or not you want a combining character.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline), an overline may be found at U+203E (spacing) or U+0305 (combining), and a macron at U+00AF or U+02C9 (spacing, and apparently identical in appearance), or U+0304 (combining).

Comment: U+0304 isexactly what i want. Thank you!

Comment: @j0h Glad to be of help!

Comment: Useful to combine _ with ‾ to make annotations like ̅_|→. On Linux, this can be done by pressing Ctrl+Shift+U, followed by the 4 Unicode characters, followed by the space or enter key and eventually followed by the character you want to combine (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en#ctrlshiftu). It worked in software like Geany but may not work in all software.

Comment: Update: the character you want to combine should be preceding the combining character instead of following it, so it becomes _̅|→ (it will not be displayed correctly for all fonts: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/284076/hide-dotted-circle-when-using-a-combining-character/).

Answer (score 14):

You could try a web service to look up the unicode character you want **by drawing**.

[Unicode character recognition](http://shapecatcher.com/)

Some results:

Horizontal scan line-3: ⎻
Unicode hexadecimal: 0x23bb

Combining double macron: ͞
Unicode hexadecimal: 0x35e

Upper one eighth block: ▔
Unicode hexadecimal: 0x2594

Combining overline: ̅
Unicode hexadecimal: 0x305

Comment: If you know the symbol name, search it on [amp-what Unicode characters & entities](http://amp-what.com/unicode/search/). Example: [Overline symbol](http://amp-what.com/unicode/search/overline)

Answer (score 7):

How to do an overline?

...   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ... I don't know.

Joke aside, here is a short way to generate them in code if you need them (you can adapt to any language, here in Python):

```
print(chr(8254)) # ‾
print(chr(175))  # ¯
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+0175 gives you upper score ¯¯

(Make sure you press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while typing the numbers)